# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when going through a string with increasing variable

Tags: c#, string, exception, char

going to try to keep it short. So I had this long code, kept getting System.IndexOutOfRangeException error, though I will start from the beginning, and it happened with a single loop, so I am asking here. The code itself is very simple, the problem is definitely somewhere here.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                for(;;)
                {
                    if(line[i] == 's' && line[i+1] == 'e' && line[i+2] == ':') break;
                    i++;

                }
                i = i + 2;
                line.Substring(i, line.Length - i);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

to explain the if statement - I am looking for when the word "exercise:" ends, so I could have what follows as a new string.

Any idea why I am getting this error? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is sample text file I would read:

> Exercise: bench press. Engaged muscle groups chest, shoulders
>
> Exercise: Shoulder press. Engaged muscle groups shoulders, biceps
>
> Exercise: Cable rows. Engaged muscle groups back, biceps

Comment: Do you have sample input?

Comment: Yes, here you go:

Exercise: bench press. Engaged muscle groups chest, shoulders \n

Exercise: Shoulder press. Engaged muscle groups shoulders, biceps \n

Exercise: Cable rows. Engaged muscle groups back, biceps \n

Had to write "\n" because comments dont have new lines.

My goal after this action would be to save the name (like have a string "bench press" and then to save the muscle groups as separate strings, and apply them as enums, but first I need to solve this problem.

Comment: You want line.length - 1, not line.length - i.  But I dont think that would cause your issue.  Are you sure it errors on those lines?  However, I would just replaced `Exercise: ` with a blank string and print that.  Also, what language is this?  And do you want Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(i, line.Length - 1))?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to use a loop for what you want. You could use string functions for extract your data, you can use something like that:

```
String exercise = "Exercise:hello";
var hello = exercise.Substring (exercise.IndexOf (":"));
```